# How to add dynamic page-size while consuming Rest Api in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, rest

I am consuming a REST API in my **service.js**: `http://server-url:8080/api/managed-data/:id?page=1&size=20` which gives me 20 elements in the json response by default.

**Edit-**

Now here's the problem, by default the page size is 20, but I've got different objects of different size. e.g I've an object of size 40, and if I consume the above API, then only 20 items are shown, with the remaining not being displayed. **What shall I do?**

Another question is what if I want to *define the page-size* for dynamic record i.e. without hard-coding the number of the records(size) to be fetched, **what shall I pass as a size of the parameter and how** *(that gets dynamically changed)*?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit... 1) you don't know how to use page&page_size parameters to get all 40 records?  (page=1,size=40)  2)  as for dynamic page size (which is, btw, not a good idea for the server due to potential huge requests) you are limited by what REST API of that particular service gives you. What does documentation say?

Comment: @VladimirM of course I can use _size=40_ but that's not the case here. I've got different objects of different size. I've updated my question, have a look.

Comment: Ok. I think, I understand now. If the API does not allow you to pass a wild-card parameter for size, then you may use a walk around, by passing a hard-codded very large page size. Still it depends on the REST API implementation. But typically, if data contains less records then the page size, it should return all the existing records to the end.

Comment: @jait23 - your question is way to vague and confusing.  You're interchanging terms like page size, object size, number of records, and items ... all of these are ambiguous and mean nothing without seeing what code you are referring to.  You need to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and modify your question based on the standards described there.